# ASP.Net Webapi Core template not working with postman

Tags: asp.net-core, postman

I have just created a brand new web API using Visual Studio 2019 and ASP.NET CORE.

I used all of the defaults except that I chose the WebAPI Template.

After It completes its template I change from starting with IIS to WebApplication1

When I build and run the project everything builds and a web browser pops up with an address of https://localhost:5001/WeatherForcast and there is data there as I would expect. So then I open PostMan up and copy past the above URL click send and get this response:

[image: reponse]

Why can I not call the web API from postman?

Default Launch Settings:

```
"WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```

**EDIT:** 
I have completely done everything over from the start of this except uncheck https and postman can connect without any issues

Comment: Are you sure the scheme is https instead of http? The 5000 or 5001 port is usually used for http, and for https is 44300 or higher.

Comment: I copied the url from chrome.

Comment: @3xGuy, This often because of SSL verification is on in Postman, turn it off: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGFXC.gif